# Error - illegal to have multiple occurrences of 'contentType' with different values

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, glassfish-4

I have a dynamic web project in Eclipse which I run on Glassfish4. In the project, there is an index.jsp file given below. When I run this jsp on the server, I get the error:

`org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp(1,1) PWC5988: Page directive: illegal to have multiple occurrences of 'contentType' with different values (old: text/html, new: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1)`

This is an internal server error with the description - The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/designs.css">
</head>
<body>

Content

</body>
</html>
```

I looked in google and other sites, but found no working solution. The server log stack trace also did not help. Please help me.

Comment: i think you have to keep one of the 2 tags, either keep @psge tag, or <meta http-equiv="Con... dont use both of them

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue is that you have "Content-Type" declared twice (as "text/html"). This against specifications and is causing your website to throw an error.

You just can't use both tags simultaneously. The HTTP protocol also provides the Content-Type encoding. So unless you know how your website is serving those pages, don't mess with Content-Type.

Comment: Go it. I cannot have the meta and page directive tag declaring the content type twice. I wonder why this error occurs even when both tags declare the same information.

Comment: I removed the meta tag in my JSP. I still get the same error. Please help me to fix it.

Comment: The Content-Type could be declared as a request header in the HTTP connection as well. If that's the case, any content-Type declared at ALL on this page might cause issues. Trying deleting both and see if it works.

Comment: You are right. Removing `content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1` from page directive tag resolves the error. Please add that to your answer. Thanks.