# How to add sites in liferay programmatically?

Tags: java, jsp, liferay

I want to add sites in a liferay programmatically so for that I had created a portlet which is responsible to add site programmatically but it's not working so please can anyone please help me in this.The error I got when I clicked create site is `Portlet is temporarily unavailable`.
This is my code:

```
<%@page import="javax.portlet.PortletPreferences"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ParamUtil"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.HtmlUtil"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.StringPool"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.UnicodeProperties"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutSetPrototypeServiceUtil"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.model.LayoutSetPrototype"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.service.GroupLocalServiceUtil"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.BeanParamUtil"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.theme.ThemeDisplay"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.model.Group"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.WebKeys"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://alloy.liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/theme"  prefix="theme"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" prefix="liferay-ui" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://alloy.liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/portlet" prefix="liferay-portlet" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />
<theme:defineObjects/>

<%

PortletPreferences commonpref = renderRequest.getPreferences();
String commonvalue = (String)commonpref.getValue("commonvalue", "Hello!   Welcome to our portal.");
//Group group = (Group)request.getAttribute("site.group");
//Group liveGroup = (Group)request.getAttribute("site.liveGroup");
LayoutSetPrototype layoutSetPrototype = (LayoutSetPrototype)request.getAttribute("site.layoutSetPrototype");
//boolean showPrototypes = GetterUtil.getBoolean(request.getAttribute("site.showPrototypes"));

long companyid=company.getCompanyId();
String languageid=user.getLanguageId();



long liveGroupId = 0;
//Group group = (Group)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.);
List<Group> objgroup=GroupLocalServiceUtil.getGroups(0,    GroupLocalServiceUtil.getGroupsCount());
Group group=objgroup.get(0);
long groupId = BeanParamUtil.getLong(group, request, "groupId");

System.out.println("Here are group :"+group);
Group stagingGroup = null;

Group liveGroup = null;

if (group != null) {
if (group.isStagingGroup()) {
    liveGroup = group.getLiveGroup();

    stagingGroup = group;
}
else {
    liveGroup = group;

    if (group.hasStagingGroup()) {
        stagingGroup = group.getStagingGroup();
    }
}
}
     liveGroupId = liveGroup.getGroupId();
     System.out.println("Here are livegroup id :"+liveGroupId);
     request.setAttribute("group", group);
    %>
   <%=commonvalue %>
  <portlet:actionURL var="creatURL" name="Create">
  <portlet:param name="viewJSP" value="/html/sites/view.jsp">   </portlet:param>

</portlet:actionURL>

<aui:form action="<%=creatURL %>" method="post">

<liferay-ui:error key="sitename" message="The site you has enter already eits" />
<aui:input name="commonvalue" type="hidden" value="<%=commonvalue %>"/>
<aui:input name="liveGroupId" type="hidden" value="<%=liveGroupId%>" />
<aui:input name="companyid" type="hidden" value="<%=companyid%>" />
<aui:input name="languageid" type="hidden" value="<%=languageid%>" />
<aui:input name="groupId" type="hidden" value="<%= groupId %>" />
<aui:input name="group" type="hidden" value="<%= group %>" />
<aui:input name="sitename" label="Enter Site" type="text" value="">
<aui:validator name="required"></aui:validator></aui:input>
<aui:input name="discription" label="Enter site discription" type="textarea" value="">
</aui:input>



 <aui:button type="submit" value="Create site" ></aui:button>






 </aui:form>
```

& this is my Sites.java which is a action file:

```
package com.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.portlet.ActionRequest;
import javax.portlet.ActionResponse;
import javax.portlet.PortletModeException;
import javax.portlet.ReadOnlyException;
import javax.portlet.ValidatorException;
import javax.portlet.WindowStateException; 
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SessionErrors;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.HtmlUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ParamUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.StringPool;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.UnicodeProperties;
import com.liferay.portal.model.Group;
import com.liferay.portal.model.LayoutConstants;
import com.liferay.portal.model.LayoutSet;
import com.liferay.portal.model.LayoutSetPrototype;

import com.liferay.portal.service.GroupServiceUtil;

import com.liferay.portal.service.GroupLocalServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutSetLocalServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutSetPrototypeServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContext;
import com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContextFactory; 
import com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil;

import javax.portlet.PortletPreferences;
//import com.liferay.portlet.sites.util.SitesUtil;
import com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet;

/**
 * Portlet implementation class Sites
 */
 public class Sites extends MVCPortlet {


public void fiveplan(ActionRequest fiveplanrequest,ActionResponse fiveplanresponse) throws ReadOnlyException, ValidatorException, IOException, PortletModeException, WindowStateException
{
    String fiveplane=fiveplanrequest.getParameter("basicplan");    

    PortletPreferences fiveplanpref=fiveplanrequest.getPreferences();

    if(fiveplane !=null)
    {
        fiveplanpref.setValue("commonvalue", fiveplane);
        fiveplanpref.store();    

        fiveplanresponse.setRenderParameter("jspPage","/html/sites/view.jsp");

    }


}



public void Create(ActionRequest actionRequest ,ActionResponse res) throws Exception
{

    try {
        String sitename=actionRequest.getParameter("sitename");
         String findsitename="";
          List<Group> siteobj=GroupLocalServiceUtil.getGroups(0, GroupLocalServiceUtil.getGroupsCount());
            for(int k=0;k<siteobj.size();k++)
            {

                if(sitename.equals(siteobj.get(k).getName()))
                {
                    //SessionErrors.add(actionRequest, "sitename");
                    findsitename=siteobj.get(k).getName();
                }

            }
         String commonvalue=actionRequest.getParameter("commonvalue");

            long liveGroupId = Long.parseLong(actionRequest.getParameter("liveGroupId"));
            long companyid=Long.parseLong(actionRequest.getParameter("companyid"));
            String languageid=actionRequest.getParameter("languageid");
            String discription=actionRequest.getParameter("discription");
            System.out.println("Here is domain name"+sitename);
            System.out.println("Here is group name"+liveGroupId);
            int type = ParamUtil.getInteger(actionRequest, "type");
            String friendlyURL = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "friendlyURL");
            System.out.println("Friendlay URL is :"+friendlyURL);
            ServiceContext serviceContext = ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(Group.class.getName(), actionRequest);
            Group liveGroup = null;
            String oldFriendlyURL = null;
            String oldStagingFriendlyURL = null;
            long privateLayoutSetPrototypeId = ParamUtil.getLong(actionRequest, "privateLayoutSetPrototypeId");
            long publicLayoutSetPrototypeId = ParamUtil.getLong(actionRequest, "publicLayoutSetPrototypeId");
            System.out.println("Here are private id: :"+privateLayoutSetPrototypeId);
            System.out.println("Here are public id: :"+publicLayoutSetPrototypeId);
            System.out.println("Here are servicecontext id: :"+serviceContext);
            ServiceContext serviceContexta = new ServiceContext();
            Group liveGroups = null;

           List<LayoutSetPrototype> layoutSetPrototypes = LayoutSetPrototypeServiceUtil.search(companyid, Boolean.TRUE, null); 
                        String uuid=null;
                        for (LayoutSetPrototype curLayoutSetPrototype : layoutSetPrototypes) 
                            {
                            UnicodeProperties settingsProperties = curLayoutSetPrototype.getSettingsProperties();
                            String servletContextName = settingsProperties.getProperty("customJspServletContextName", StringPool.BLANK);
                            String name=HtmlUtil.escape(curLayoutSetPrototype.getName(languageid));
                            System.out.println("hi this is :"+ curLayoutSetPrototype.getLayoutSetPrototypeId());

                              if(commonvalue.equals(name))
                                  {
                                uuid=  curLayoutSetPrototype.getUuid();
                                  }
                                  name="";
                            }

                              if(!uuid.equals(""))
                              {

                                 if(findsitename.equals(""))        

                                 {                                    
                                GroupServiceUtil.addGroup(sitename,discription, 1, friendlyURL, true, true ,serviceContext);

                                Group groupobj=GroupLocalServiceUtil.fetchGroup(companyid, sitename);
                                long groupid=groupobj.getGroupId();
                               System.out.println("Site is creates"); 
                               LayoutSet layoutsets=LayoutSetLocalServiceUtil.getLayoutSet(groupid,false); 

                               layoutsets.setLayoutSetId(layoutsets.getLayoutSetId());
                               layoutsets.setGroupId(layoutsets.getGroupId());
                               layoutsets.setCompanyId(layoutsets.getCompanyId());
                               layoutsets.setCreateDate(layoutsets.getCreateDate());
                               layoutsets.setModifiedDate(layoutsets.getModifiedDate());
                               layoutsets.setPrivateLayout(layoutsets.getPrivateLayout());
                               layoutsets.setLogo(layoutsets.getLogo());
                               layoutsets.setLogoId(layoutsets.getLogoId());
                               layoutsets.setThemeId(layoutsets.getThemeId());
                               layoutsets.setColorSchemeId(layoutsets.getColorSchemeId());
                               layoutsets.setWapThemeId(layoutsets.getWapThemeId());
                               layoutsets.setWapColorSchemeId(layoutsets.getWapColorSchemeId());
                               layoutsets.setCss(layoutsets.getCss());
                               layoutsets.setPageCount(1);
                               layoutsets.setSettings(layoutsets.getSettings());
                               layoutsets.setLayoutSetPrototypeUuid(uuid);
                               layoutsets.setLayoutSetPrototypeLinkEnabled(true);

                               LayoutSetLocalServiceUtil.updateLayoutSet(layoutsets);




                               boolean privateLayout = ParamUtil.getBoolean(actionRequest, "privateLayout");
                               long parentLayoutId = ParamUtil.getLong(actionRequest, "parentLayoutId");
                               String name1 = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "name", "home");
                               String title = StringPool.BLANK;
                              String description = StringPool.BLANK;

                               boolean hidden = false;
                               String friendlyURL1 = StringPool.BLANK;


                               ServiceContext serviceContext1 = ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(actionRequest);
                               System.out.println("Service cintext is "+serviceContext1);

                               System.out.println("Here are new site id"+groupid);

                              LayoutServiceUtil.addLayout(groupid, false ,parentLayoutId ,name1 ,title ,description ,LayoutConstants.TYPE_PORTLET ,false ,friendlyURL1,serviceContext);
                              res.setRenderParameter("jspPage", "/html/sites/view.jsp");

                                     }
                                else
                                {

                                SessionErrors.add(actionRequest, "sitename");


                                }


                              }

         }
    catch (SystemException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
    }    

}

}
```

my log file is:

```
13:08:51,568 ERROR [RuntimePageImpl-5][render_portlet_jsp:132] null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.test.Sites.Create(Sites.java:118)
at  com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.callActionMethod(LiferayPortlet.java:163)
at  com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.callActionMethod(MVCPortlet.java:249)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.processAction(LiferayPortlet.java:90)
at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.processAction(MVCPortlet.java:212)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:71)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:112)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:583)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:628)
```

Comment: Could you share you logs? You can't exclude it is just a portlet configuration....

Comment: Please include information as described in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823

Comment: Yes, now your logs shows an error at line 118 of Sites.java... but if I copy and paste your Sites.java on a texteditor to search for line 118, then it is a blank line! Can you paste the same (and full) version of your file that is deployed?

Comment: in my 118 line the code is like this: if(!uuid.equals(" ")){...

Comment: or u can see the code in [link]http://liferay-by-akaram4u.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-create-new-site-programmaticly.html?showComment=1458308001022#c2431263250324296181

Comment: Its quit clear that uuid value is NULL and hence you are getting NPE when you invoke uuid.equal("")

Comment: For me that line is 119... see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your problem should be related to a `NullPointerException` to the line `if(!uuid.equals(""))`.

The only nullable object is `uuid`.

Looking your code, it is possible that nothing will ever be assigned to `uuid` due to following test: `if(commonvalue.equals(name))`.

In my mind, because you are testing for empty values of `uuid`, it can be enough to replace in line 104 (or 103?) `String uuid=null;` with `String uuid = "";`

Comment: But it showing me now:" Your request failed to complete.The site you entered already exits."

Comment: Also in this case it is necessary to watch application logs... maybe there is an other error...

Comment: In my log file the error is: javax.portlet.PortletException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /html/login/view.jsp (line: 11, column: 1) Page directive: illegal to have multiple occurrences of contentType with different values (old: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1, new: text/html)
javax.portlet.PortletException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /html/login/view.jsp (line: 11, column: 1) Page directive: illegal to have multiple occurrences of contentType with different values (old: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1, new: text/html)

Comment: It seems that you are defining twice the content type... it is possible that it is happening because you are declaring it, and the import file chain is importing another one that declares it. Try to remove it if any in your code... more explain here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743585/error-illegal-to-have-multiple-occurrences-of-contenttype-with-different-val

Comment: done that now it showing me: ERROR [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][AutoDeployDir:220] com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployException: sites-portlet-6.2.10.1.war does not support this version of Liferay

Comment: For new kind of problems it's always better to perform a search, then to post a new question (in order to allow to anyone to see it, otherwise noone, apart me, may help you)... btw the solution should be to verify liferay-plugin-package.properties: take a look here https://www.liferay.com/it/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/23252853